# Powershell extracting IIS Bindings

Tags: excel, powershell, iis

I have an `Excel` spreadsheet that has about 190 lines worth of `IIS` bindings. What I need to do is go line by line and get each binding from the line.

Example from one line could be:

> SITE "Gateway"
>   (id:1,bindings:http/192.168.1.1:80:www.sample.test.com,http/192.168.1.1:80:sample.test.com,https/192.168.1.1:443:,net.tcp/808:*,net.pipe/*,net.msmq/localhost,msmq.formatname/localhost,state:Started)

So I would need to seperate out the two webpages, www.sample.test.com and sample.test.com. Then what I wanted to do was do an nslookup on each webpage that is pulled out from each line.

I have gotten as far as going line by line and getting each set of bindings using:

```powershell
$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item($sheetname1)
For ($1=0;$i -le 190;$i++) {
$a = $worksheet.Columns.Item(1).Rows.Item($i).text}
```

Edit:

I have added the following code and it seems to work (but is there a better way to do this?)

```powershell
 For ($1=0;$i -le 190;$i++) {
$a =@($worksheet.Columns.Item(1).Rows.Item($i).text)
For ($2=0;$2 -lt $a.length; $2++) {
$a[$2].split(':,')[5]
$a[$2].split(':,')[8]
$a[$2].split(':,')[11]
$a[$2].split(':,')[14]
$a[$2].split(':,')[17]
 }
```

I got it to work with this but now my issue is that some of the lines dont have more than two host names to do the nslookup so in the output file I get extra data that I dont want

```powershell
$a =@($worksheet.Columns.Item(1).Rows.Item($i).text)
    For ($2=0;$2 -lt $a.length; $2++) {
    $d = $a[$2].split(':,')[5] | Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append
    $a[$2].split(':,')[5] | nslookup($_) | Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append
    $e = $a[$2].split(':,')[8]  |Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append
    $a[$2].split(':,')[8] | nslookup($_) | Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append 
    $f = $a[$2].split(':,')[11]  |Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append
    $a[$2].split(':,')[11] | nslookup($_) | Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append 
    $h = $a[$2].split(':,')[14]  |Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append
    $a[$2].split(':,')[14] | nslookup($_) | Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append 
    $j = $a[$2].split(':,')[17]  |Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append
    $a[$2].split(':,')[17] | nslookup($_) | Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append 
    $k = $a[$2].split(':,')[20] |Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append
    $a[$2].split(':,')[20] | nslookup($_) | Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append 
    $l = $a[$2].split(':,')[23]  |Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append
    $a[$2].split(':,')[23] | nslookup($_) | Out-File -Filepath $outfile -append}
```

Comment: Might be useful to add a tag for whatever language that is. PowerShell?

Comment: Yes it is Powershell, I have added the tag